# Using Trix editor with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using the gem 'trix' for the Trix editor with Simple Form. This is what I did in my form:

```
<%= f.input :body, as: :trix_editor %>
```

and I get "No input found for trix_editor". The documentation for the gem only talks about using it with Formtastic. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `<%= f.trix_editor :body %>` ?

Comment: I did and it gives me the error: "undefined method 'body' for" (model).

Comment: does your model have an attribute called "body"?

Comment: Thanks. Attribute was missing. Works now. My rustiness with Rails is showing.

Comment: Added an answer for others coming to this page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should work

```
<%= f.trix_editor :body %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it too:

```
<%= f.rich_text_area :body %>
```